# Which is correct: "eucharistic" or "Eucharistic"? Or is there no hard rule?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, religion

Recently I have been writing a question at https://christianity.stackexchange.com. I have noticed that browser underlines word "eucharistic".

As I am neither English nor catholic, I do not know any rule for capitalisation of the word.
Is there some rule for that or is it just a catholic custom to appreciate the idea behind the word?

Comment: I'm voting to close as Primarily Opinion-Based, on the grounds that 6 out of the full OED's 12 example citations are capitalised, but ***the other 6 are not***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I consider "it is opinion-based as there is no consensus" a valid answer.

Comment: You are of course entitled to your opinion. But obviously there's a *reason* why Stack Overflow explicitly provide the option of citing "POB" in closevotes (on ***all*** SO subsites, I believe; the substance of this issue is clearly something that matters a great deal to them).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand the rule is to prevent fighting over which opinion is better. If there is no hard rule in the language, this is the precise, not OB answer. Anyway, it seems I already have my answer in your comment, so thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers All those citations are from before 1900, I'm not sure whether a good argument is to be made based on that. People back then capitalized things willy-nilly compared to now.

Comment: @AzorAhai: My argument is that *there is no consensus* (which I believe strongly argues for the question being Off Topic POB). But if you specifically want to focus on *later* written instances, have a look at [this NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+eucharistic%2Ca+Eucharistic&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20eucharistic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20Eucharistic%3B%2Cc0) It clearly shows that usage was pretty evenly split until *half* a century ago, since when the uncapitalised version has become increasingly dominant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is a more convincing argument, IMO.

Comment: @Azor: On reflection, you did have a valid point, and I should have acknowledged that. Before commenting under the question itself, I'd originally been "provoked" into looking at OED in because I took issue with "It's always capitalised" in one of the answers. As you correctly say, until a century or two ago all sorts of words would be almost randomly capitalised. I think it was almost always *nouns*, not adjectives - but things could get murky when we're talking about an adjective directly derived from a proper noun that's almost always still capitalised itself! :)

Comment: ...I'd also say that there's an ongoing general trend to reduce capitalisation where it serves no *necessary* purpose. Thus, no-one ever texts the exclamation **OmG!** They're not actually thinking of the specific "xtian" God in [My God, My God, why have you forsaken me?](http://biblehub.com/matthew/27-46.htm) For similar reasons, I look things up by ***googling*** them (and I'd probably still do that if I used a different search engine). And only law-frit Americans would think of capitalising *when they hoover the carpet*. Capitals are **out**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I appreciate the acknowledgement and also agree with you capitalization is trending down, although I don't think Americans would say "hoover the carpet" in any case ... apparently that's an old vacuum company.

Comment: @Azor: "hoover the carpet" became [solidly established](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hoover+the+carpet&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Choover%20the%20carpet%3B%2Cc0) in BrE in the 70s. The company still exists, but now owned by the privately-owned Italian ***Candy*** conglomerate. Whose brand name I only associate with cheapo washing machines - I've certainly *never* heard of anyone speak of ***candying their laundry**!*

Comment: Note that you generally *do* capitalize "Catholic", when used as a religious designation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard rule. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application. In other words, there is no single standard. For what it's worth, the [Religion Stylebook](http://religionstylebook.com/entries/eucharist) published by the Religion Newswriters Association (RNA) capitalizes *Eucharist* but is silent on adjectival uses:

> **Eucharist** A term commonly used by Roman Catholics and Eastern Orthodox Christians and High-Church Anglicans for Communion, but some Protestants use it as well. In the Holy Eucharist, the Lord Christ is contained, offered, and received in the form or presentation of bread and wine. See *[Communion](http://religionstylebook.com/entries/communion)*.

The word *Eucharist* may encompass many different concepts: the sacrament and its related doctrines, a type of worship celebration (also known as the *Mass*, *Holy Communion*, the *Divine Liturgy*, the *Lord's Supper*, and so on), a specific part of of that worship service (the *Liturgy of the Eucharist*, but also to the distribution of Holy Communion), or to the sacramental food and drink distributed at that service (held in Catholic, Orthodox, and High Church traditions as the Body and Blood of Christ).

Because in Catholic belief, the Eucharist (as sacramental food) is synonymous with the Body and Blood of Christ, reference to it is consistently capitalized. The [style guide for the Archdiocese of Milwaukee](http://www.archmil.org/ArchMil/Resources/COMM/FinalMilwArchStyleGuide2011.pdf) is typical:

> **sacraments** Catholics and Orthodox recognize seven sacraments. The word *sacrament* is lowercase. Capitalize only *Eucharist*, lowercase all other sacraments: baptism, confirmation, penance (or reconciliation), matrimony, holy orders, the sacrament of anointing of the sick (formerly extreme unction).

Adjectival uses, however, are lowercased, e.g.

> **eucharistic adoration** Always lowercase the term *eucharistic adoration*.

The [Episcopal Church style guidelines](https://www.episcopalchurch.org/files/the_episcopal_church_guidelines.pdf) are very similar:

> **sacraments** Capitalize the proper names used for a sacramental rite that commemorates the life of Jesus Christ or signifies a belief in his presence: the Lord’s Supper, Holy Communion, Holy Eucharist. Use lowercase for the names of other sacraments: baptism, confirmation, penance (sacrament of reconciliation), matrimony, holy orders, and the sacrament of anointing the sick (formerly extreme unction).

In practice, things are a real jumble, even in official documents specifically on the topic referring unambiguously to the consecrated host (yet another term), e.g. USCCB

> [J]ust as natural food gives nourishment to the body, so the eucharistic food gives spiritual nourishment.

Answer (score 2):

Well into the 20th century, a text discussing Christian teaching and liturgical practice, particularly in a devotional setting, would look something like this:

> Understood simply, [*Eucharistic Adoration*](http://www.catholic-church.org/kuwait/eucharistic_adoration.htm) is adoring or honouring the Eucharistic Presence of Christ. In a deeper sense, it involves "the contemplation of the Mystery of Christ truly present before us".
>
> During Eucharistic Adoration, we "watch and wait", we remain "silent" in His Presence and open ourselves to His Graces which flow from the Eucharist ... By worshiping the Eucharistic Jesus, we become what God wants us to be! Like a magnet, The Lord draws us to Himself and gently transforms us. — Apostolic Vicariate of Kuwait.

The only change a 17th c. writer might make to this text would be capitalizing *contemplation* as a significant noun and not likely using a magnet as a ready simile. The [reverential capitalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverential_capitalization) of pronouns with divine antecedents, however, is primarily a 19th c. novelty: neither the Catholic Douay-Rheims Bible nor the KJV did so, but it became an almost ubiquitous practice in that century among all English speakers, remaining [a topic of discussion](https://www.osv.com/MyFaith/Article/TabId/586/ArtMID/13752/ArticleID/10551/Why-not-He-Him.aspx) today.

Beginning in the 1970s, writers across most denominations began to use lower case more frequently:

> The starting point for [*eucharistic*](https://blessedsacrament.com/eucharistic-spirituality-2/) spirituality is the table of the Lord Jesus, a truth affirmed at the Second Vatican Council and underscored in the Catechism of the Catholic Church:  “The Eucharist is the source and summit of the Christian life.” — Congregation of the Blessed Sacrament.

This tendency is traceable in the frequency trends of [*Biblical/biblical*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Biblical%2Cbiblical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBiblical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbiblical%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

The collocation *Eucharistic action/eucharistic action*, i.e. looking analytically at the shape and performance of the ritual, is not likely to occur in a devotional setting. The practice of capitalization [follows the same trend](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eucharistic+action%2CEucharistic+action&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceucharistic%20action%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEucharistic%20action%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

By the same token, one can refer to a specific text as the [*Eucharistic Prayer*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Eucharistic+prayer%2Ceucharistic+prayer%2CEucharistic+Prayer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CEucharistic%20prayer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceucharistic%20prayer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEucharistic%20Prayer%3B%2Cc0), a *eucharistic prayer* as a representative of a text genre, or a *Eucharistic prayer* with a capital letter from *Eucharist* as the name of the sacrament or the entire liturgy in which it is embedded:

[image]

These NGrams suggest that the current default is lower case *eucharistic* unless there are specific devotional reasons for capitalizing it. That means that a capitalized *Eucharistic* would more likely appear, say, on a church website, but far less likely in academic works of liturgical scholarship.

These are, however, only trends and preferences not fixed into any kind of “rule.” The best cue would be the practice of those writing the same sort of texts you wish to write and that of the speech community you wish to address. In an academic context, it is always prudent to ask the instructor.

Answer (score 0):

'Eucharist' is a proper noun for the name of the feast of the Lord's Supper. It's always capitalised.

I'm not surprised that spellcheck underlines 'Eucharistic' as this is the first time I've ever seen that word (though the meaning is obvious). I would capitalise it as it's derived from a proper noun that's not commonly used. Cf the adjectives Christian or Protestant.

Note also that if you're referring to the Roman Catholic Church you need to capitalise the word 'Catholic'. The word catholic with small 'c' is normally used to refer to the meaning of the word, meaning the 'universal' church of Christ. E.g. the Apostle's Creed used by the Church of England says 'I believe in the Holy Spirit, the holy catholic Church ...' referring to the universal Christian religion, but quite separate from Roman Catholicism.

Comment: I'm sure quite a lot of people (not just Catholics) would say that since ***Eucharist*** is a proper noun, the derived adjectival form should also be capitalised. But interestingly, although the full OED (subscription-only, sorry! :)  capitalises the entry **Eucharistic**, of the 12 example citations they give, fully ***half of them*** are non-capitalised. So it's certainly not "always capitalised", even if some people would *like* it to be so.

Comment: A scan of search results from the [COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/COCA/) shows a good third of the results are lowercased _eucharist_. A sentence from an academic journal has this sentence: _Even those who advocate a broadly inclusive " inductive ecclesiology " or " ecclesiology from below " stress the centrality of the **eucharist**. Paul Lakeland says unequivocally, " without the **Eucharist** we have no Church, " while Roger Haight points to BEM's common apostolic understanding of the **eucharist** " as the central act of the church's worship. "_